# jQuery element coordinates

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').mousedown(function(event) {
            $('p').text('Mouse Clicked x =' + event.screenX + ' Y = ' + event.screenY);
        });
    });
```

Which nicely finds the screen co ordinates of the cursor if they click on the image, but what I would actually like is the co-ordinates within the image they clicked (1,1 for top left, regardless of the images location in the page) but I can't see anyway of doing this other than to place the image in it's own page and use pageX/pageY ... or am I looking at this wrong

Comment: Find the boxing coordinates of the image, and subtract the mouse coord from the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works so far as I can tell:

```
$('img').mousedown(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        imgLeft = e.pageX - offset.left,
        imgTop = e.pageY - offset.top;

    $('p').text('Mouse clicked x = ' + imgLeft + ' Y = ' + imgTop);
});
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/5qxtL/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subtracting the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` of the image (and its parents) from your numbers?

You may need to `while` through the `offsetParents` to get all of the `offset`s.

Comment: this.offsetTop and left both contain 0, which screenX/Y contain 17 and 230, so it doesn't seem to match

Comment: Try out `this.offsetParent.offsetTop`.  The parent element(s) have an `offsetTop` also.  That's what I was saying with the `while` - you might have to loop through them and add up their offsets to get the true offset of the image.

Comment: This is useful as a generic JavaScript answer, but as he's said he's using jQuery, he can rely on jQuery's handling of all of this stuff for him.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `screenX` and `screenY`, you want [`pageX`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [`pageY`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/). You can then easily subtract the image's position (retrieved via [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)) to determine where within the image was clicked:

```
$('img').click(function(event) {
  var imgPos;

  imgPos = $(this).offset();
  display('Mouse click at ' + event.pageX + 'x' + event.pageY);
  display('Image at ' + imgPos.left + 'x' + imgPos.top);
  display(
    'Delta within image: ' +
    (event.pageX - imgPos.left) +
    'x' +
    (event.pageY - imgPos.top)
  );
});

function display(msg) {
  $("<p/>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/acozu4)